# Compiling all of the boost libraries on Unix?

Tags: c++, unix, boost

I used one of the ubuntu package manager commands to install all of the boost libraries. I think the command was

> sudo install something libboost

I am aware that some of the boost libraries need to be compiled separately (or something similar). How do I go about doing this so that I can use them along with the regular libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

Comment: hey thanks. will that mean I have to change any of my eclipse paths (I used boost default paths) or will the files still be put into the same place?